# Count number of unique purchase dates

Tags: oracle10g

I have a log of purchases made by customers. Sometimes a customer purchases multiple items during a given purchase, other times they only purchase a single item.  What I want to do, on a line by line basis, is identify which purchase events have happened (i.e. not on an item by item basis, but on a checkout by checkout basis).

Each row of the source database contains the following fields

```
cust_id, purchase_date, sku
```

So a customer who purchases three items during a given transaction would look like this

```
1, 01/01/01, dog1
1, 01/01/01, cat1
1, 01/01/01, mouse1
1, 01/02/01, wolf1
1, 01/03/01, lion1
```

WHat I want out is

```
cust_id, purchase_date, sku, item_purchase_number_within_purchase, unique_purchase_date_across_dates
```

And that would look like

```
1, 01/01/01, dog1, 1, 1
1, 01/01/01, cat1, 2, 1
1, 01/01/01, mouse1, 3, 1
1, 01/02/01, wolf1, 1, 2
1, 01/03/01, lion1, 1, 3
```

In words, on the first date, three items where purchased arbitrarily identified as purchase numbers, 1, 2, and 3, on the second purchase date (Jan 2nd, 2001), only a single item was purchase, but this was the second purchasing event, and then on the third purchasing date (Jan 3, 2001) there was another single item purchased.

I'm trying to do this in oracle10g.  I'm not sure how to describe what I'm accomplishing.

This is the sql I have so far

SELECT
cust_id, purchase_date, sku, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  purchase_date ORDER BY sku)
FROM
[table]

Thanks

Comment: Why are the first three all the same 'event' - you're assuming that all purchases by the same customer on a given date are one event?

Comment: They have the same customer id, and the same date.

Comment: Yes, for the sake of simplicity and this example I'm assuming that all purchases by the same customer on a given date are one event.  It was just easier than putting in a total time stamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()` (or `rank()`) to avoid gaps. With your sample data in a CTE:

```
with t (cust_id, purchase_date, sku) as (
  select 1, date '2001-01-01', 'dog1' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2001-01-01', 'cat1' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2001-01-01', 'mouse1' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2001-01-02', 'wolf1' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2001-01-03', 'lion1' from dual
)
select cust_id, purchase_date, sku,
  dense_rank() over (partition by cust_id, purchase_date order by sku)
    as item_within_purchase,
  dense_rank() over (partition by cust_id order by purchase_date)
    as purchase_event
from t;

   CUST_ID PURCHASE_D SKU    ITEM_WITHIN_PURCHASE PURCHASE_EVENT
---------- ---------- ------ -------------------- --------------
         1 2001-01-01 cat1                      1              1
         1 2001-01-01 dog1                      2              1
         1 2001-01-01 mouse1                    3              1
         1 2001-01-02 wolf1                     1              2
         1 2001-01-03 lion1                     1              3
```

The first extra column is partition by both customer and date, and ordered by SKU as you had; the second is only partitioned by customer, and ordered by date.

Comment: I was thinking order lines vs # of customer orders but yeah :P